# KeyPath with operators and NSArray

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have a class Person defined as

```
@interface Person : NSObject {
    NSString *name;
    int age;
    NSArray *workedHours;
}

@property (nonatomic,retain) NSArray *workedHours;

-(int)age;
-(void)setAge:(int)val; 
-(NSString*)name;  
-(void)setName:(NSString*)val;
@end
```

I'd like to bind the workedHours sum to a label...

```
-(void) awakeFromNib{
    [label bind:@"value" toObject:person withKeyPath:@"@sum.workedHours" options:nil];
}
```

And i obtain this error: 
`this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key @sum.`

`label` is an IBOutlet and `person` a property of my NSWindowController. 
If i try to change the keyPath with "@name" it works correctly.

What is wrong ? Can i maybe use @sum, @count, @avg etc only with NSArrayController ?

Comment: What I'm more curious about is why you choose to you @property syntax for worked hours, but you're writing accessory manually for name and age rather than making them properties as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that the workedHours array is not a collection of objects that is KVC compliant.

If, for example, you used a daily work record of the form:

```
@interface DailyWork : NSObject {
   NSDate *day;
   int hours;
}
@property(retain) NSDate *day;
@property int hoursWorked;
@end
```

Then, this should work, since the collection operator expects to perform an operation on a field of the objects that are being collected.    So, if you stuck DailyWork* values in your NSArray, for example: @"workedHours.@hours" would give you the total of all hours worked in each of the objects in workedHours (the array of DailyWork*).